# Using more than one WMS layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

I have a problem when using WMS layers in QGIS.

I am loading a WMS layer containing some aerial images, and then on top of it another WMS layer that contains information of the city, boundaries etc with labels. When I load the WMS layer with the labels, the background goes blank and I can't visualise the aerial images.

I have tried the same thing in ArcMap and it works fine but I have to use QGIS.

Comment: Can you give more information on the WMS services.  For example what software are they being served by?

Comment: Combining different WMS in one project shouldn't be a problem, I just tested this in QGIS 2.2.0. But they need to share a common projection (you might have to choose the correct one manually from the list)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens to me when I started using QGIS 2.x. I then realize that the default parameter for the image format was set on JPEG and thus not allowing transparency (and I couldn't see the layers below).

When you click on the Add WMS layer icon and open the window with the parameter for the WMS layers, you have a parameter called " image encoding" below the list of layers: just check the **PNG option** (PNG allows for transparency) and it should solve the problem of the background going blank (or rather being covered, as I suspect).

This will work if you don't have any other issues of course, especially related to projection systems .